# How to find relative path to load js from assets folder

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have some javascripts in Assets folder that I want to load in my html file when needed as I need to use innerhtml at times.

I am not able to find the relative path I should use that I can refer my js from. I have a windows phone 8.1 c# project.
on using

```js
<script>function myFunction() { document.getElementById(\"demo1\").innerHTML= window.location.pathname ;}</script>
```

I get `\blank` ,so I am not able to find the location I am at. Is there any hint anyone has?